# How to avoid similar colors being picked for fill and color scales?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, fill, color-palette

**Context:** I would like to use viridis color palette for a color scale and a fill scale within the same plot. The geoms I use do not all have a `color` or a `fill` argument so it is not possible to "blend" everything into one scale. In other words, I want to use the same palette but make sure that each color from this palette is used only once across scales, while keeping the properties of the viridis palette (printing and colorblind friendly).

**Problem:** when using `scale_color_viridis_d()` and `scale_fill_viridis_d()` I end up with colors being shared across the fill and the color scale which make the final plot difficult to read.

**Question:** is it possible to tell ggplot to pick different colors within the viridis palette across the fill and the color scales?

```r
library(ggplot2)
# example dataset
zones <- data.frame(starts = c(1, 3, 4),
                    ends = c(2, 3.75, 5),
                    item = rep("A", 3))
# current plot, note that the same color from viridis scale is picked
ggplot(data = zones) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = starts, xmax = ends, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "areas")) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = starts, xend = ends, y = item, yend = item, color = "segments")) +
  scale_color_viridis_d() +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

**Expected output:** different colors from the same palette being used for the fill and the color scales. Here I used `begin =`  and `end =` arguments from the `scale_*_viridis_d()` functions but I feel this is not optimal as many colors are "lost" by spliting the palette like this.

```r
# look of the expected output
ggplot(data = zones) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = starts, xmax = ends, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "areas")) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = starts, xend = ends, y = item, yend = item, color = "segments")) +
  scale_color_viridis_d(begin = 0.5, end = 1) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(alpha = 0.5, begin = 0, end = 0.49)
```

[image]

[EDIT]
I got a step closer using `aesthetics` and `guide` arguments of `scale_fill_viridis_d()` but it messes the legend:

```r
ggplot(data = zones) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = starts, xmax = ends, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "areas")) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = starts, xend = ends, y = item, yend = item, color = "segments")) +
  # scale_color_viridis_d() +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(alpha = 0.5, 
                       aesthetics = c("color", "fill"), 
                       guide = guide_legend("Highlights"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: So you want both the colour and fill scale to convey independent information about different variables, but you want to use the same colours to represent them? Are you sure that's the way to go with your visualisation? What you're asking is feasible,  but it may require a little effort, and it's not clear how useful it would be in the end.

Comment: @AllanCameron I would like to use the same palette (*i.e.* viridis) for the fill and the color scales. But I want to avoid the situation you describe, that is ending up with the same color from the viridis palette being used within both scales. In other words, I want to use the same palette but make sure that each color is used only once across scales while keeping the properties of the viridis palette (printing and colorblind friendly)

Answer (score 3):

I guess the simplest way would be to get the viridis color in reverse order. Normally it's from deep purple to yellow, with the `direction = -1` argument, we can have it from yellow to deep purple.

```r
library(ggplot2)
zones <- data.frame(starts = c(1, 3, 4),
                    ends = c(2, 3.75, 5),
                    item = rep("A", 3))

ggplot(data = zones) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = starts, xmax = ends, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "areas")) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = starts, xend = ends, y = item, yend = item, color = "segments")) +
  scale_color_viridis_d(direction = -1) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your asnwer, I will use it for now but I was wondering if is was possible to tell ggplot not to pick similar colors in a more "general" way, maybe using `guide()` or some other tools.

Comment: @Paul Another thing you can do would be pre-assign the colours in separate vectors and use it in your `scale_*()` functions. However, I'm not sure will it be more "general". Let's wait to see if there's other alternatives from someone else :)

Comment: In fact I tried the `direction = -1` with my real data and ended with similar colors with only 4 needed. But it is a straight and nice way to go for 3 or less colors.